# How do I register a Go To Webinar attendee to a specific session using their API V2?

Tags: reactjs, api, logmein, webinar

OK so...through a custom form, I am successfully registering attendees to Go To Webinar but am blocked if there are multiple sessions of the same webinar. Currently, I am returning scheduled sessions to populate our dropdown menu (response shown below) but am challenged with passing back `sessionKey` with the [registration payload](https://developer.goto.com/GoToWebinarV2/#operation/createRegistrant). Has anyone successfully done this? Help! I've also put in an inquiry with GTW so will let folks know what I hear if others are struggling with this also. Thanks!

```
[{
    webinarKey: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
    registrantsAttended: 0,
    webinarID: "xxxxxxx",
    sessionKey: 666666,
    startTime: "2020-05-06T19:27:54Z",
    endTime: "2020-05-06T20:01:13Z"
  },
  {
    webinarKey: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
    registrantsAttended: 0,
    webinarID: "xxxxxxx",
    sessionKey: 777777,
    startTime: "2020-05-07T19:26:08Z",
    endTime: "2020-05-07T19:26:43Z"
  }]
```

Comment: @GillsoftAB - thanks for the help -- I have used their Postman examples / curl GET requests to receive the above data but can't complete a POST including the registrant's chosen `sessionKey`. There doesn't seem to be a way to include it in the body. Do you suppose it can be appended to the --location?

Answer (score 0):

1. Populate a list for the webpage visitor using [Scheduled
   webinars](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/3306419/SztD6TZc?version=latest#b65e8ee4-a41b-4575-96c3-cf7d92feadc9)
2. An interested individual selects a webinar from the list
   and you submit their details using [Create registrant](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/3306419/SztD6TZc?version=latest#26d26273-3f92-4b66-b393-a9f5e631d51b)

For step 2 you should also know the following:

*To use the second version of the api you must pass the header value*

**'Accept: application/vnd.citrix.g2wapi-v1.1+json'**

*instead of 'Accept: application/json'.*

**Leaving this header out results in the first version of the API call.**

Comment: How do I account for the chosen `sessionKey` , a child of a given `webinarKey`? I don't see how `sessionKey` is ever passed back either in the `body` or appended to `--location`